# PHP JSON returning NULL

Tags: php, json

I've got a JSON file, which I want to retrieve with PHP, but when I try to show the values on screen, it returns NULL.

JSON:

```
{
"categorias": [
    {
        "nombre": "Fundamentos",
        "subcategorias": [
            {
                "nombre": "Colores",
                "modulos": [
                    {
                        "seccion": "<b>Colores</b>",
                        "objetos": [
                            {
                                "imagen": "sketches/fundamentos/preview/colores.png",
                                "titulo": "",
                                "texto": "",
                                "class": "full-width",
                                "noLink": true
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "nombre": "Tipografías",
                "modulos": [
                    {
                        "seccion": "<b>Tipografías</b>",
                        "objetos": [
                            {
                                "imagen": "sketches/fundamentos/preview/tipografias.png",
                                "titulo": "",
                                "texto": "",
                                "class": "full-width",
                                "noLink": true
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "nombre": "Iconografía",
                "modulos": [
                    {
                        "seccion": "<b>Iconografía</b>",
                        "objetos": [
                            {
                                "imagen": "sketches/fundamentos/preview/tipografias.png",
                                "titulo": "",
                                "texto": "",
                                "class": "full-width",
                                "noLink": true
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "unique": false
    }
]}
```

I read and tried many other solutions, that json must be encoded with utf-8, but I couldn't achieve it. It's really been a while since I coded with PHP, so I'm very rusty right now.

PHP:

```
$archivo = file_get_contents("../json_info.json");
$json_data = json_decode($archivo); //here I also tried to include "encode"
var_dump($json_data);
```

Also I tried:

```
$error = json_last_error();
```

With encode_json returns 0, and without it returns a 4.

I hope you can lend me a hand with it.

**Edit/Update**

As some told me, I tried adding the json in the same directory. Added also "true" to json_decode:

```
$archivo = file_get_contents("json_info.json");
$json_data = json_decode($archivo, true);
```

And this returns NULL.

Comment: check the value of `var_dump($archivo);` and let us know what is coming

Comment: Your path is wrong `file_get_contents("../json_info.json")` Do not use absolute path.

Comment: `json_last_error` returning **4** indicates a syntax error in the string. The JSON you've posted looks valid, so it could be an issue with the file encoding (a Unicode BOM, for example)

Comment: Your code should work fine check your path as @Pedram suggested

Comment: also, json_decode($json, true); will keep the array keys. add true!

Comment: @Pedram I'll try putting the json in the same directory, let me check it out

Comment: @AlivetoDie let me check it out and I'll copy it. It returns the string of the json

Comment: @iainn mmm, I'll try the to copy the structure on a separate file and try there if there's something wrong.

Comment: @iainn it looks it was something with the BOM (something strange since I use Brackets and the only charset format it accepts it's UTF-8). Add it to the answer and I could use it as the solution =)

Answer (score 0):

Your json is very poorly built.
But i don't know. Maybe you have to work with it.
This code works 100%;

For example

```
$archivo = file_get_contents("../json_info.json");
$json_data = json_decode($archivo);

print_r($json->categorias[0]->nombre);
```

You get

```
Fundamentos
```

OR

```
  print_r($json->categorias[0]->subcategorias);
```

Outputs

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [nombre] => Colores [modulos] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [seccion] => Colores [objetos] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [imagen] => sketches/fundamentos/preview/colores.png [titulo] => [texto] => [class] => full-width [noLink] => 1 ) ) ) ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [nombre] => Tipografías [modulos] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [seccion] => Tipografías [objetos] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [imagen] => sketches/fundamentos/preview/tipografias.png [titulo] => [texto] => [class] => full-width [noLink] => 1 ) ) ) ) ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [nombre] => Iconografía [modulos] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [seccion] => Iconografía [objetos] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [imagen] => sketches/fundamentos/preview/tipografias.png [titulo] => [texto] => [class] => full-width [noLink] => 1 ) ) ) ) ) )
```

It is right. You have 3 items in your top object categories. 
subcategorias has 3 dictionaries. Everything is nice. The only problem you could have is path. If you build this script in other, it will get current path from executable file and not from one that is included.

Comment: The file it's just something I was trying from another project that was a bit messy, but it was working. It looks was something related with the Unicode BOM that iainn told on the comments. I tried doing another file with similar structure, and now is working.